# Can LUIS handle compound entities with a slash?

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I am building a LUIS intent for the submission of blood pressure. Blood pressure consists of systolic and diastolic blood pressure. I am therefore trying to group the two into a compound entity for overall blood pressure. In spoken language, the word "over" is used to separate them. In written language, a forward slash (/) is used. I have tried to train LUIS on both formats with example utterances. But whereas it easily picks up the version with "over", it doesn't work with the slash. Instead it only picks up the entity before the slash, but not the one following it.

**Good:**
my bloodpressure is { [ $SystolicBPQuantity ] over [ $DiastolicBPQuantity ] } .

**Bad:**
bloodpressure { [ $SystolicBPQuantity ] / 90 } .

I have tried numerous times to mark the second entitiy as DiastolicBPQuantity. It even let's me do it, but then forgets about it again.

Thanks for any suggestions! I think as a last resort I might put the word "slash" into my utterance and have my input parser replace any forward slashes with "slash" before passing it on to LUIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the ModifyLuisRequest method in LuisDialog and using it now to replace forward slash with "over". Works like a charm.